# Unable to resolve dependency tree when using npm install error

Tags: npm-install, dependency-tree

So when I cloned a project and ran `npm install` in my bash terminal, it gave me this "unable to resolve dependency tree" error. I checked to see if I wasn't in any subfolder and I deleted my node_modules and package-lock.json as well. I have node version 12.18.3 and npm version 7.12.1. I'm certain I have updated both of them. I even ran the command `npm i --force` and `npm i -legacy-peer-deps` and both didn't work.
[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yka6Z.png)

Comment: Were you on the right directory when you ran npm install?

Comment: @Shah Yes. I wasn't in any subfolder and I deleted my node_modules and package-lock.json as well

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting node_module, package-lock.json, and then run the following:

1. `npm cache verify`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`